# Is it possible to change a height of an element with css transform functions?

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, cordova, gpu

I'm writing an app over PhoneGap and I'm using css and jquery. I know I can `scale` an element but it doesn't seem to have an effect on its visible height. It just shrinks but still keeps space. I need somehow a GPU accelerated height maninpulation. GPU accelerated display/hide would also be fine.

Thanks.

EDIT: the structure I have is

slides-container 
--- slides
------ slide

slides-container has `width: 320px; overflow: hidden;` to create a window for the slide to slide. When I remove overflow: hidden; it works fine but then I lose the sliding effect.

Whats happening actually is wheneever I do a move to a slide with a larger height, there is a white flash. I set the slide heights after the movement.

Comment: As far as I know, height cannot be animated with CSS3 transitions, min-height can however.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto

Comment: If you don't want to tinker around with that though, I'm sure there are many jQuery solutions (albeit not a GPU accelerated one)

Comment: I don't think you can control the GPU with phoneGap ... Btw, have you used percentages or fixed heights ?

Comment: @SeanDunwoody, height works just fine. The only restriction is animating to `auto` which cannot be automagically converted to a number..

Comment: Apologies, fuzzy memory + laziness to double check (it's friday)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV you can actually use trasform functions to do so. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/

Comment: I ll have a chance to check these on Monday. Will let know of the outcomes but I see things around what I was looking at so should come with something good. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. Just haven't implemented it correctly yet.

I think I've seen some people talk about it before but its basically about changing the height of a slide in a container which has is not big enough. Changing the height of the container fixes the issue. What I'm not 100% sure is that to which value should I change height of the container. Anyway that my issue. I ll let know if I find something generic though.

For now I would say make sure the container can fit its elements inside.

Also besides;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
this
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
also helps.

Comment: Also one extra thing that helped me was moving the overflow: hidden; to the parent of the div with  overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll; Just thought it might help to someone

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Phonegap but if you can use jQuery you can create a jQuery animation function on the element.

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({height : '200px'},100);
});
```

The animate function works as follows. ({CSS to manipulate},duration,callback function);
The duration is measured in milliseconds and the callback function isn't required.

Some CSS methods such as margin-left and background-colour are different. Margins are written like so marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop. 
Background-color and any other with a python require to be entered as a string. "background-image".

Hope this was useful.

Comment: Beneto, Thanks for the reply. My initial attempt was this and this works perfectly on a browser but on iphone (via PhoneGap) it causes a white flash when the height is changed to a large value. I tried css animations as well but nothing helps as far as I can see. I sense there is a DOM Update causing this flash. -webkit-backface-visibility won't even solve my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is it a mobile application website or a mobile website? What are you using Phonegap for?

Comment: It's a mobile app written with jQuery, css using PhoneGap. I'll try a couple of stuff talked here and I'll come back with a solution.